# Wordpress wp_remote_post vs wp_remote_request

Tags: wp-remote-post, wp-remote-request

I'm somehow new to Wordpress and its API and while writing an simple Rest Service to an remote Server i have been asked to use the native wp_remote_X functions.
Right now i have some trouble to distinguish between them both:

```
wp_remote_post() 

wp_remote_request().
```

Does it make any difference which one to use or is the wp_remote_request an alias to missing wp_remote_delete() and wp_remote_update() ?

Comment: The documentation for `wp_remote_request()` explains what the difference is: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/#description Have you read that?

Comment: Yes, but I have only found this explanation: "Performs an HTTP request and returns its response."... which does not really explains the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use both `wp_remote_request()` and `wp_remote_post()` for a 'POST' request, as they are just wrappers for the same [`WP_Http::request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/) method that supports the methods:

```
'GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 
'DELETE', 'TRACE', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH'.
```

and the default one is 'GET'.

The difference is that `wp_remote_post()` function has the 'POST' method explicitly set via [`WP_Http::post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/post/) that's also a wrapper for [`WP_Http::request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/).